# .Netcore mvc get floating number

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Something seems wrong when I try to get a floating/double number from a razor page.

My razor syntax:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-9">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
             <input type="number" asp-for="TestFloating" class="form-control" min="0.01" max="0.6" step="0.01" required>                          
          </div>    
     </div>
</div>
```

On submit my action from controller get the TestFloating as a hole number so instead of 0.02 gets 2 instead of 0.2 gets 2 instead of 0.01 gets 1 and so on.
The action header is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(MyModel model)
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{

    [Display(Name="Test floating")]
    public float TestFloating{ get; set; }
}
```

I have been testing this is chrome but i don't think that is a problem.
Any ideas how can I fix this?

**Update:** I am on a windows 10 home, running the app on kestrel server.

Comment: What is the culture on the server (is it one that accepts a dot as the decimal separator)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm on windows 10, kestrel server the default one :)

Comment: The default will be what your culture is (which I assume is one that has a comma as the decimal separator). Change the culture to say `en-US` and test it.

Comment: oh got it now. That was a dumb questions from me.